# AWSIotException: Cross account not allowed when trying to attach policy

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm trying to generate and attach a policy to my certificate. I use the next code:

```
String topicName = String.format("certificates/%s", certificateId);
String policyName = String.format("Policy_%s", certificateId);
String target = String.format("arn:aws:iot:%s:123456789012:cert/%s", region, certificateId);
String policy = String.format(POLICY, certificateId, topicName, topicName);
awsIotClient.createPolicy(new CreatePolicyRequest().withPolicyDocument(policy).withPolicyName(policyName));
awsIotClient.attachPolicy(new AttachPolicyRequest().withTarget(target).withPolicyName(policyName));
```

I get an error when trying to perform `awsIotClient.attachPolicy(...)` :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.iot.model.AWSIotException: Cross account not allowed. (Service: AWSIot; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: b943-.....
```

My user account has AdministratorAccess permissions. Why I got this error and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a mistake. It is accountId in arn:aws:iot:%s:123456789012:cert/%s . My AWS user has another accountId and I tried to add the policy to another account_ID so I got Cross account not allowed error.